# Correct HTTP response header

Tags: http

I am using Safari to test my C++ socket handler, I send a request to the application, in the address bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8124/?{%22module%22:%22mdFileIO%22,%22command%22:%22open%22}
```

In my application I send a response:

```
const QString CRLF("\r\n");
QString strContent(strResponse)
       ,strDtNow(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toUTC().toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
       ,strHdr = "200 OK" + CRLF
               + "Content-Type: application/json" + CRLF
               + "Content-Length: " + QString::number(strContent.length()) + CRLF
               + "Date: " + strDtNow + " GMT" + CRLF + CRLF;
strResponse = strHdr + strContent;
```

In the above 'strContent' contains:

```
{"ack":"ack","module":"mdFileIO","time":"2020-10-05 18:00:19"}
```

The output for the response looks like this:

```
200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 62\r\nDate: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 18:25:59 GMT\r\n\r\n{\"ack\":\"ack\",\"module\":\"mdFileIO\",\"time\":\"2020-10-05 18:25:59\"}
```

The return from write() is 161.  Safari shows the following:
[image]

Comment: this is due to you not correctly specifying the status line, the status line should be `HTTP/version status_code status_message` (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` for your code), you set it to just `200 OK`, causing the browser to guess the HTTP version (my guess is 0.9 is the default one)

Comment: HTTP/0.9 is deprecated (it was released back in 1991), therefore safari refuses to show the website, nowadays, mostly HTTP/1.1 is used, HTTP/1.0 can also be used altough it contains a very limited subset of features compared to the standard HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0 is mostly used on embedded servers where it isn't desired for additional headers to be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of errors in the header:

1. The header should have started with "HTTP/1.1 "
2. The Content-Type should have been: "application/jsonrequest"

Comment: I have personally never met the `application/jsonrequest` MIME type you're referring to, it isn't listed in the [IANA application/* MIME type reference](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application) either, however `application/json` [is](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json), could you perhaps link some specification supporting the existence of this MIME type?